# Django render doesn`t give a view

Tags: django, forms, post, render

I`ve got in urls.py redirecting to as_view() method of ClassView after pressing "Search" button
There is an if such as:

```
def as_view():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       //sth
   elif request.GET.get('test1') or request.GET.get('test2'):
       //sth
   else:
       form = myForm()
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'form' : form, 'arg': self.arg})
```

There is strange situation: on my home computer it works but on any other not.
In details, I`ve got this files on server and Im connecting to the server, switching on configured virtualenv on server and than make runserver 0:port

When I do this on my home computer everything is ok, but if I connect then to the http:// sererIP:port from another computer, press "Search" button which execute method as_view() it comes to this "else" in code then form is initialized but return render doesn`t give me anything and there is white page only. When I checked in server output I got

```
[07/May/2013 05:54:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

in red color.

After connecting to the server from laptop and making runserver 0:port I had the same problem even on this laptop. I tried than to test in connecting from home computer and also I got white page.

Comment: You should not override `as_view()`. Use `get()`, `post()`, `delete()` such methods and use `as_view()` only in the `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_view()` of a class based view isn't supposed to return an http response, but a callable function...
If you want to send out a response for a `GET` request, add a `get` method to you view class:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(request):
        # return your http response here
```

If you want to browse Django's class based views a bit, here's [a nice documentation](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.base/View/)!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Django FormView? [This is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView).

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = myForm
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #This is you GET
        return super(MyFormView. self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #This is after the post, when the form is valid
        return super(MyFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        #This is after the post, when the form is invalid
        return super(MyFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

You can play with `get_succes_url()` method to redirect so somewhere.

I Hope that helps.